# Internal networking breaks after update from Docker 19.03.15 to 20.10.5

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I'm using the following docker-compose.yml to run a dockerized GitLab instance with one runner. Both are in the same network. (The bridge name is set explicitly because the firewall rules depend on it.)

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8022:22'
    environment:
      [...]
    volumes:
      [...]
  runner:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine'
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    hostname: 'gitlab-runner.example.com'
    depends_on:
      - 'web'
    environment:
      [...]
    volumes:
      [...]
networks:
  default:
    driver: 'bridge'
    ipam:
      driver: 'default'
      config:
        - subnet: '172.16.1.0/24'
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: 'br-gitlab'
```

This works fine on Docker 19.03.15, but after an upgrade to 20.10.5, the `runner` can't connect to `web` anymore from where it pulls the source. Doing the same manually from a Bash inside `runner` renders the same "connection refused":

```
$ curl https://gitlab.example.com/user/repo.git/
Connecting to gitlab.example.com (172.16.1.2:443)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.16.1.2): Connection refused
```

There's network in the `runner` container, I can reach other sites and resolve domain names as well. And apparently, it's not related to iptables (on the host), the problem persists after shutting down those firewalls.

I've checked the Docker changelogs, but don't see any change which explains this. Any idea what I don't see here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

My setup causes the `runner` to fetch the sources from gitlab.example.com:443 which is the port served by the Nginx proxy on the host. This worked on Docker 19, however, as of Docker 20 the `runner` container can't connect via the host anymore. This is totally okay, the solution: Tell the `runner` to contact the GitLab server in `web` directly when cloning the source. Each runner in `config.toml` has to contain:

```
url = "http://172.16.1.2:8080/"
clone_url = "http://172.16.1.2:8080/"         # <- this one was missing
```